# Stream a movie on Netflix on LG Smart TV

Tags: television, netflix, lg, live-connect-sdk

I am trying to stream a movie on Netflix on LG Smart TV using the connect SDK. I know that I can start the YouTube app using the ConnectSDK, but can someone help me understand how I can use ConnectSDK to play a particular video on netflix on my LG Smart TV given the video ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for can be found in the [Android API Sampler](https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Android-API-Sampler/blob/master/src/com/connectsdk/sampler/fragments/AppsFragment.java#L156-L166) for Connect SDK. Here is a snippet that may help you out.

```
device.getLauncher().launchNetflix("<< NETFLIX CONTENT ID >>", new Launcher.AppLaunchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LaunchSession session) {
        setRunningAppInfo(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ServiceCommandError error) { }
});
```